# NullReferenceException on SetContentView () after launching camera intent

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, nullreferenceexception

I'm getting very strange behavior only on HTC devices. My application works a 100% on all other devices except on HTC devices.

The issue happens after I have launched the camera intent and I pop back to previous layouts and then try to navigate back to the activity that launched the camera intent. I get a null reference error in the `setContentView()` method in `OnCreate()`.

I have included my `LaunchCameraIntent` and `OnActivityResult()` functions.

Anyone have an idea?

I have read on another thread that it could be an HTC specific issue that occurs when an intent is launched from an activity and that for some reason the Garbage Collector is called to clear that activity and thus when trying to navigate back this results in a nullreference error.

Here is the thread

http://mono-for-android.1047100.n5.nabble.com/Crash-on-HTC-td5710360.html

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
   base.OnCreate (bundle);
   this.SetContentView (Resource.Layout.PhotoAccidentCarLayout);
}

private void LaunchCameraIntent (int picType)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Android.Provider.MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
        MDCarPicStatus.PicUri = ContentResolver.Insert (isMounted ? Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri : Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.InternalContentUri, new ContentValues ());
        intent.PutExtra (Android.Provider.MediaStore.ExtraOutput, MDCarPicStatus.PicUri);
        intent.PutExtra ("isCamera", true);
        MDCameraHelper.isCamera = true;
        StartActivityForResult (intent, picType);
    }

protected override void OnActivityResult (int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {

        if ((resultCode == Result.Ok)) {
            if (data == null) {
                SaveImage (MDCarPicStatus.PicUri, (PhotoType)requestCode);
            } else {
                if (data.Data == null) {
                    SaveImage (MDCarPicStatus.PicUri, (PhotoType)requestCode);
                } else {
                    SaveImage (data.Data, (PhotoType)requestCode);
                }
            }
        }


        base.OnActivityResult (requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }
```

this is my stack trace

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_void__this___intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr_JValue[] (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) <IL 0x00062, 0x00153>
  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (intptr,intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mac-monodroid-4.2.6-branch/632e6ddf/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:612
  at Android.App.Activity.SetContentView (int) [0x0006b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mac-monodroid-4.2.6-branch/632e6ddf/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-8/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:3119
  at CCIC.MD.PhotoAccidentCarActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) [0x00009] in c:\Work\Sepia\Source\mobipro02.exordia.co.za\CCIC\trunk\CCIC.MD\CCIC.MD\Activities\Claim\PhotoAccidentCarActivity.cs:41
  at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00010] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mac-monodroid-4.2.6-branch/632e6ddf/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-8/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:1490
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.2b7db9d6-0abc-4175-b134-cda100e112d6 (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00012, 0x00033>
```

Anyone have any idea? Thank you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/SecondaryAndroidBackgroundNoLogo"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
  <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
  android:minWidth="25px"
  android:minHeight="25px">
<RelativeLayout
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
  <TableLayout
      android:minWidth="25px"
      android:minHeight="25px"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/tableLayout2"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true">
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2">
      <TableLayout
          android:minWidth="25px"
          android:minHeight="25px"
          android:layout_column="0"
          android:id="@+id/tableLayout3">
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px">
          <TextView
              android:text="Front Left"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
               android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:layout_column="0"
              android:id="@+id/textView44"
              android:textColor="#ff003508" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px">

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/btnFrontLeftCamera"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="50sp"
              android:scaleType="fitCenter"
              android:src="@drawable/AndroidCameraImage" />

        </TableRow>
      </TableLayout>
      <TableLayout
          android:minWidth="25px"
          android:minHeight="25px"
          android:layout_column="2"
          android:id="@+id/tableLayout4">
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px">
          <TextView
              android:text="Front Right"
               android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
              android:layout_column="0"
              android:id="@+id/textView44"
              android:textColor="#ff003508" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px">

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/btnFrontRightCamera"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="50sp"
              android:scaleType="center"
              android:src="@drawable/AndroidCameraImage" />

        </TableRow>
      </TableLayout>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3">
      <TableLayout
          android:minWidth="25px"
          android:minHeight="25px"
          android:layout_column="0"
          android:id="@+id/tableLayout6"
          android:layout_gravity="center">
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow12"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px">
          <TextView
              android:text="Left Side"
               android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
              android:layout_column="0"
              android:id="@+id/textView44"
              android:textColor="#ff003508" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow13"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px">

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/btnLeftSideCamera"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="50sp"
              android:layout_column="0"
              android:scaleType="center"
              android:src="@drawable/AndroidCameraImage" />

        </TableRow>
      </TableLayout>

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/imageView6"
          android:layout_width="100sp"
          android:layout_height="250sp"
          android:layout_column="1"
          android:scaleType="centerInside"
          android:src="@drawable/AndroidCarAlone" />

      <TableLayout
          android:minWidth="25px"
          android:minHeight="25px"
          android:layout_column="2"
          android:id="@+id/tableLayout5"
          android:layout_gravity="center">
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow9"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px">
          <TextView
              android:text="Right Side"
               android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
              android:layout_column="0"
              android:id="@+id/textView44"
              android:textColor="#ff003508" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow10"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px">

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/btnRightSideCamera"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="50sp"
              android:scaleType="center"
              android:src="@drawable/AndroidCameraImage" />

        </TableRow>
      </TableLayout>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4">
      <TableLayout
          android:minWidth="25px"
          android:minHeight="25px"
          android:layout_column="0"
          android:id="@+id/tableLayout7">
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow14"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px">
          <TextView
              android:text="Back Left"
               android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
              android:layout_column="0"
              android:id="@+id/textView44"
              android:textColor="#ff003a03" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow15"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px">

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/btnBackLeftCamera"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="50sp"
              android:layout_column="0"
              android:scaleType="center"
              android:src="@drawable/AndroidCameraImage" />

        </TableRow>
      </TableLayout>
      <TableLayout
          android:minWidth="25px"
          android:minHeight="25px"
          android:layout_column="2"
          android:id="@+id/tableLayout8">
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow16"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px">
          <TextView
              android:text="Back Right"
               android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
              android:layout_column="0"
              android:id="@+id/textView44"
              android:textColor="#ff003a03" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow17"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px">

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/btnBackRightCamera"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="50sp"
              android:scaleType="center"
              android:src="@drawable/AndroidCameraImage" />

        </TableRow>
      </TableLayout>
    </TableRow>
    <LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="80sp"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px"/>
  </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Probably the problem is in your Resource.Layout.PhotoAccidentCarLayout. Provide the xml of this layout

Comment: I have added the requested xml. I doubt that the issue lies here. Unless it is an issue with the tab controller? I have a main dashboard screen in the app that launches multiple activities (a dashboard screen). When I start the activity(lets call it dashActivity1) that itself has an activity that launches the camera intent (PhotoAccidentCarLayout) the issue pops up. After that I will get a null reference exception when trying to start any activity within dashActivity1. For a couple of seconds there is no issue launching activities... it only kicks in in about 4 seconds. STRANGE!